# Hide Approve/Reject Buttons in Fiori Master Details Page

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am looking to hide the Approve/Reject Buttons in the Details Page of a Fiori App based on certain filter conditions. The filters are added in the Master List view (Left hand side view) thru the view/controller extension. 
Now, if the user selects certain type of filter ( Lets say, Past Orders) - then the approve/reject button should not be displayed in the Order Details Page.
This is how I have defined the buttons in the Header/Details view

```
 this.oHeaderFooterOptions = {
                       oPositiveAction: {                       
                        sI18nBtnTxt: that.resourceBundle.getText("XBUT_APPROVE"),
                        id :"btn_approve",
                        onBtnPressed: jQuery.proxy(that.handleApprove, that)
                       },

                   oNegativeAction: {                   
                    sI18nBtnTxt: that.resourceBundle.getText("XBUT_REJECT"),
                    id :"btn_reject",
                    onBtnPressed: jQuery.proxy(that.handleReject, that)
                   },
```

However at runtime, these buttons are not assigned the IDs I mentioned, instead they are created with IDs of __button0  and __button1.

Is there a way to hide these buttons from the Master List View?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Recommended:**
SAP Fiori design principles only talk about disabling the Footer Buttons instead of changing the **visibility** of the `Button`.
[Read More here about Guidelines](http://experience.sap.com/fiori-design/ui-components/button/)

Based on filter conditions, you can disable like this:

```
this.setBtnEnabled("btn_approve", false);
```

to enable again: `this.setBtnEnabled("btn_approve", true);`

Similarly you can change Button text using `this.setBtnText("btn_approve", "buttonText");`

**Other Way:** As [@TobiasOetzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3816959/tobiasoetzel) said use

```
this.setHeaderFooterOptions(yourModifiedHeaderFooterOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call setHeaderFooterOptions on your controller multiple times eg:

```
//Code inside of the controller
_myHeaderFooterOptions = {
    oPositiveAction: {                       
        sI18nBtnTxt: that.resourceBundle.getText("XBUT_APPROVE"),
        id :"btn_approve",
            onBtnPressed: jQuery.proxy(that.handleApprove, that)
        },
    oNegativeAction: {                   
        sI18nBtnTxt: that.resourceBundle.getText("XBUT_REJECT"),
        id :"btn_reject",
        onBtnPressed: jQuery.proxy(that.handleReject, that)
    }
},

//set the initial options
onInit: function () {
    this.setHeaderFooterOptions(this._myHeaderFooterOptions);
},

//modify the options in an event
onFilter : function () {
    //remove the negative action to hide it
    this._myHeaderFooterOptions.oNegativeAction = undefined;
    this.setHeaderFooterOptions(this._myHeaderFooterOptions);
},

//further code
```

so by manipulating the _myHeaderFooterOptions you can influence the displayed buttons.

Comment: Hi Tobias - Thanks for your reply. Well the issue is the filter event handler is defined in a different controller (S2 List) and the buttons are in S3 Header View. In this case, how do I control the visibility of the buttons?

Comment: Hi, you can fire an event over the event bus of your component see https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Component.html. You publish the event in the S3 controller and you subscribe in the S2 controller. Subscribe handler you modify the headerFooterOptions

Comment: HI Tobias - thats a good idea. thanks for your reply. sorry for getting back late. Instead of getting the global event bus, is there way to get the event bus of the component? That would be appropriate I think.

Comment: Hi,in the link i posted there is a function described myComponent.getEventBus(). This event bus will send events only visible to this event bus instance

Answer (score -1):

First, you should use **`sId`** instead **`id`** when defining HeaderFooterOptions, you can get the footer buttons by **`sId`**, for example, the Approve button.

```
this._oControlStore.oButtonListHelper.mButtons["btn_approve"]
```

Please check the following code snippet:

**S2.view.controller:** You have a filter event handler defined following and use [EventBus](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.EventBus.html) to publish event `OrderTypeChanged`  to `S3.view.controller`.

```
onFilterChanged: function(oEvent) {
    // Set the filter value, here i use hard code
    var sFilter = "Past Orders";
    sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish("app", "OrderTypeChanged", {
         filter: sFilter
    });
}
```

**S3.view.controller**: Subscribe event `OrderTypeChanged` from `S2.view.controller`.

```
onInit: function() {
    ///
    var bus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
    bus.subscribe("app", "OrderTypeChanged", this.handleOrderTypeChanged, this);

},

getHeaderFooterOptions: function() {

    var oOptions = {

        oPositiveAction: {
            sI18nBtnTxt: that.resourceBundle.getText("XBUT_APPROVE"),
            sId: "btn_approve",
            onBtnPressed: jQuery.proxy(that.handleApprove, that)
        },

        oNegativeAction: {
            sI18nBtnTxt: that.resourceBundle.getText("XBUT_REJECT"),
            sId: "btn_reject",
            onBtnPressed: jQuery.proxy(that.handleReject, that)
        }
    };
    return oOptions;

},
handleOrderTypeChanged: function(channelId, eventId, data) {
    if (data && data.filter) {
        var sFilter = data.filter;
        if (sFilter == "Past Orders") {
            this._oControlStore.oButtonListHelper.mButtons["btn_approve"].setVisible(false);
        }
        //set Approve/Reject button visible/invisible based on other values 
        //else if(sFilter == "Other Filter") 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Allen, thanks for your reply. sorry for getting back late. Instead of getting the global event bus, is there way to get the event bus of the component?

Comment: ok, so i got the event bus of the component..var c = sap.ui.core.Component.getOwnerIdFor(this.getView());
  var localEventBus = sap.ui.component(c).getEventBus();  localEventBus.publish("zPrApp","showHideApprovalButtons",{id:sButtonId}); And then in the other view controllerlocalEventBus.subscribe("zPrApp","showHideApprovalButtons", this.handleApprovalButtonsVisibility, this);                 This works fine on desktops, but fails in iPhone.Weird. The error on phones is Reject Button is undefined.this._oControlStore.oButtonListHelper.mButtons returns only the Approve Button..Any suggestions..

Comment: Hi, i tried under Chrome iPhone emulator and it is working for Reject Button. Strange.

Comment: Allen, I tried in real iPhone and Chrome simulator, reject button does not work. Do you see the Reject Button as an ActionSheet or is it displayed right along side Approve. In my case Reject Button is coming as ActionSheet.

Comment: Hi, could you please try get this._oControlStore.oButtonListHelper.oOverflowList.mButtons to see if the Reject button is in there?if it is, there is a indicator of that._oControlStore.oButtonListHelper.bHasOverflow.

Comment: Hi allen,facing a strange issue with this. The hide/show event does not work on the first time on iphones. when the app load, if you click directly any of the filter on S2 view, it goes to S3 view but the buttons are not hidden..it happens only for the first time, and that too if you click the filter directly.

Comment: -1 is for using private variables. its not recommended to use variables with _someVariable.. inner implementation may change with new SAPUI5 versions.. Hence don't use