# Remove "Claim" Button from Fiori inbox

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to remove or at least disable the "Claim" button from the footer of the inbox in SAP Fiori.
I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144794/hide-approve-reject-buttons-in-fiori-master-details-page#) but it only describes removing the approve / reject buttons, which have own properties in the `oOptions`.

Probably the claim button is located in the `buttonList` array, but setting it like this has no effect:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/m/MessageToast",
  "sap/m/Dialog",
  "sap/base/Log",
  "sap/ui/model/Filter",
  "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator",
  "sap/ui/model/Sorter",
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (MessageToast, Dialog, Log, Filter, FilterOperator, Sorter, Controller) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("something.controller.App", {
    onInit: function () {
      this._headerFooterOptions = {
        buttonList: []
      };
      this.setHeaderFooterOptions(this._headerFooterOptions);
      // ...
    }
  });
});
```

Another possible way could be disabling the button via `this.setBtnEnabled(sid, false);` but since I don't know the `sID` of the claim button, I can't check this.

I would really appreciate help with this issue!

EDIT: I have no access to the backend, in case anybody has the same issue but can access the backend, see [@MrNajzs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65719018/5846045).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Gateway/Backend solution:

There is an option to hide buttons like *Forward*, *Release*, *Claim* via a gateway/backend class. IMO you should go for this approach, and not by extending the MyInbox UI5 app.

1. Create a subclass in your gateway based on the class `/IWPGW/CL_TGW_FACADE_BWF_V2`.
2. Redefine the method `MAP_TASK_ADDITIONAL_FLAGS`. For example, if task id = XXX, don't show *Forward*, *Claim*, ...

   ```
   CALL METHOD SUPER->MAP_TASK_ADDITIONAL_FLAGS
     CHANGING
       IS_TASK = is_task
       .

   if is_task-TASK_DEF_ID CS 'XXX'. "your workitem task id
     clear: is_task-TASK_SUPPORTS-FORWARD,
            is_task-TASK_SUPPORTS-CLAIM,
            is_task-TASK_SUPPORTS-TASKOBJECT,
            is_task-TASK_SUPPORTS-RESUBMIT.
   ENDIF.
   ```
3. Open the provider implementation in spro in your gateway system (sry for german language)
   [image]
4. replace your zclass with the standard class `/IWPGW/CL_TGW_FACADE_BWF_V2`
   [image]
5. Voilà
   [image]

---

### Frontend solution:

If you have no access to the backend extend the MyInbox via WEBIDE.
In your case you can extend the whole controller(S3.controller.js) or implement a UI Controller Hook(S3.controller.js->extHookChangeFooterButtons). For Extensibility of SAP Standard Apps always take a look at [SAP Fiori Apps Reference Library](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps(%27F0862%27)/W23)

Example (S3.controller.js - UI Controller Hook Implementation):

```js
    extHookChangeFooterButtons: function (oButtonList) {
        var sTaskDefinitionId = this.getView().getBindingContext().getProperty("TaskDefinitionID");
        switch (sTaskDefinitionId) { //Define your condition
        case "XXX":
            oButtonList.aButtonList = []; // No Buttons
            break;
        case "XYZ":
            oButtonList.aButtonList.splice(1,1) //No Claim Button
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I should have mentioned that I have no access to the backend. So sadly this is no option for me.

Comment: Added frontend solution